# Tab, Fragments and Listviews

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I have an activity that shows a listview, the listview is contained within a fragment.

I now need to expand the view by adding a number of other listviews (essentially filters) on the existing listview.

I plan to use a tab construct, ideally all using the same fragment.

1) Is it possible for the same fragment to be referenced multiple times within one XML layouts, if so I assume each one will need a different tag.

2) Can the tabhost be set up in such a way that it can just use the same fragment and I can manage the adapter to perform the filtering.

Which would be the best method to use?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) instead of putting a ListView inside a Fragment. Then you have an adapter to which you give your items. Use the same adatper, because I assume the view of items inside your list doesn't change after having applied a filter.

Last, use a [SearchView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html) and use its method `setOnQueryTextListener()` to define a new Listener. Apply your filter here on your list of items. Finally, give this filterd list of items to your adapter.